# Tail inequality for r.v. with $L^p$ norms bounded by a power of $p$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Suppose it exists a $p_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $p\geq p_0$ there exist $r>0$
\begin{equation*}
    \lvert\lvert X\lvert\lvert_{L^p}\leq C p^r.
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbb{P} (\lvert X\lvert >t)\leq C \exp\left(-ct^{\frac{1}{r}}\right).
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to apply Chernoff bound and compute $\mathbb{E}[\exp(\mu X^{1/r})]$. We have:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[\exp(\mu X^{1/r})]= \sum_{p\geq 0}\frac{\mu^p}{p!}\lvert\lvert X\lvert\lvert_{L^{p/r}}^{p/r}= \sum_{p<rp_0}\frac{\mu^p}{p!}\lvert\lvert X\lvert\lvert_{L^{p/r}}^{p/r}+\sum_{p\geq rp_0}\frac{\mu^p}{p!}\lvert\lvert X\lvert\lvert_{L^{p/r}}^{p/r}
\end{equation}
For the first sum, I can bound $\lvert\lvert X\lvert\lvert_{L^{p/r}}^{p/r} \leq \lvert\lvert X\lvert\lvert_{L^{p_0}}^{p/r}\leq (Cp_0^r)^{p/r}=C^{p/r}p_0^p$ and get
\begin{equation}
\sum_{p<rp_0}\frac{\mu^p}{p!}\lvert\lvert X\lvert\lvert_{L^{p/r}}^{p/r}\leq \sum_{p<rp_0}\frac{\mu^p}{p!}C^{p/r}p_0^p \leq \exp(\mu C^{1/r}p_0).
\end{equation}
For the second sum, I apply the bound of the assumption and Stirling approximation (in order to get rid of the power $p^p$) and get
\begin{equation}
\sum_{p\geq rp_0}\frac{\mu^p}{p!}\lvert\lvert X\lvert\lvert_{L^{p/r}}^{p/r} \leq \frac{e}{\sqrt{2\pi p_0}}\sum_{p\geq 0} \mu^p C^{p/r}e^{13p}\leq \frac{e}{\sqrt{2\pi p_0}}\frac{1}{1-\mu C^{1/r}e^{13}}
\end{equation}
if $\mu C^{1/r}e^{13}<1$. So all together we get
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[\exp(\mu X^{1/r})]\leq \exp(\mu C^{1/r}p_0)+\frac{e}{\sqrt{2\pi p_0}}\frac{1}{1-\mu C^{1/r}e^{13}}
\end{equation}
and by Chernoff
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X\geq t)\leq \inf_{0<\mu<(C^{1/r}e^{13})^{-1}}\exp(-\mu t^{1/r})\left(\exp(\mu C^{1/r}p_0)+\frac{e}{\sqrt{2\pi p_0}}\frac{1}{1-\mu C^{1/r}e^{13}} \right)
\end{equation}

**Problem** Now if I try to optimise the RHS of the above display, computations get very messy. Does anyone have a recommandation on how to bound the RHS in order to get the claim?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to optimize over $\mu$. Once you find a $\mu_0>0$ such that
$\mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\mu_0\lvert X\rvert^{1/r}\right)\right]<\infty$, you get
$$
\mathbb P(\lvert X\rvert >t)\leqslant \mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\mu_0\lvert X\rvert^{1/r}\right)\right]\exp\left(-\mu_0 t^{1/r}\right).
$$